# Looping json data then send to database with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have json data like this :

**myjsondata**

```
[

{
"id_user":"31"
},

{
"id_user":"32"
},

{
"id_user":"33"
}

]
```

then i send the data with jquery $.post

```
$.post("myaction.php",
{send: myjsondata }, function(res) {


 }, "json");
```

then in myaction.php, i decode the json and i want to send the data to database with foreach :

**myaction.php**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect( "localhost","root","","mydb");

$data = json_decode($_POST['send']);

foreach($data as $row){

    $id_user = $row->id_user;

}

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbl_user 
(id_user) VALUES ('$id_user') ");
```

when i running that code, the data already inserted to the table , but the data only inserted with last id_user

**tbl_user**

```
id_user

33
```

i want all data is inserted into the table like this

**tbl_user**

```
id_user

31
32
33
```

how can i do that?
thanks

Comment: move your query into inside the foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thats totally logic. Lets take a look at your code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect( "localhost","root","","mydb");

$data = json_decode($_POST['send']);

foreach($data as $row){

    $id_user = $row->id_user;

}

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbl_user 
(id_user) VALUES ('$id_user') "); // Here is the problem!!!!
```

In your foreach loop you overwrite the `$id_user` variable. Then only at the end you insert. So what can you do? Simply put the insert query inside the foreach loop and it will work.

**Working solution:**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect( "localhost","root","","mydb");

$data = json_decode($_POST['send']);

foreach($data as $row){

    $id_user = $row->id_user;
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbl_user 
    (id_user) VALUES ('$id_user') "); 

}
```

Comment: @MuhammadRifqiMaulaturRahman Glad that I could help. May you should also take a look at http://bobby-tables.com and learn a bit about SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the query into the for loop

```
$conn = mysqli_connect( "localhost","root","","mydb");

$data = json_decode($_POST['send']);

foreach($data as $row){

    $id_user = $row->id_user;

    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbl_user (id_user) VALUES ('$id_user') ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st:** Move your `query` into inside the `foreach loop`

```
foreach($data as $row){

    $id_user = $row->id_user;

    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbl_user (id_user) VALUES ('$id_user') ");
}
```

**2nd :** Try to use prepared statement

**Cause :** your `overwriting`  `$id_user`  in foreach loop and your executing query after foreach loop so `$id_user` only contains last row value only .so Move your query into inside the `foreach loop`

Answer (score 1):

`myaction.php` File will be like this .

```
$conn = mysqli_connect( "localhost","root","","mydb");

$data = json_decode($_POST['send']);

foreach($data as $row){

    $id_user = $row->id_user;

    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbl_user (id_user) VALUES ('$id_user') ");
}
```